# How to watch multi fields with angularjs formly?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I have six product dropdown in two fieldgroups, when user pick any one of them, I need go through all six and get a summary.
With Formly, I am not sure what is the right way to do it. It seems in custom validation code I cannot access the form scope. I can access fields in same fieldGroup, but I have two now.
All fields are stored in a object in the form scope, hard to use $watch. I want to add ng-change on each field, but not sure how to add that to formly field

Any idea?

Comment: a little html code would be highly appreciable. You can provide it on http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue

Comment: Thanks, I have a fully example, and what I want to do here, please take a look.  http://jsbin.com/vuxije/edit?js,output